# Consuming SOAP on a Android Application

Tags: android, web-services, soap

So I´ve been trying to consume this SOAP WebServices in a Android APP.
Our connections is a HTTPS protocol and everytime i try to query it, I get this error log.

```
09-27 15:07:07.911 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes I/Buscando....: Chamando WebService para consulta de Clientes
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
09-27 15:07:07.927 11010-11038/br.com.testes.consultaclientes W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl
```

Comment: you are missing the root cert in the certificate chain. Please check the certificate in your keystore.

Comment: I am a beginner, you can give me a hint where I can look the certificate chain? @Reddy

Comment: If you have the url you can run it in the browser and download the certificates. After you have the certificates you will need to install them in the truststore. you should be able to find help online.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the server certificate was expired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, checked with the server administrator and he found that the SSL certificate was expired.